# flexslider data- navigation

Tags: jquery, flexslider

By default, the flexslider navigation is `1-2-3-4`.

[I've made a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26ca9/) showing the default navigation. If you look at my slides, I've added `data-slideName` which I need to use instead of the default `<ol></ol>` navigation.

From previous testing, I believe this is where I need to work in order to do so. (*Note: I've figured this out by adding content inside the  tag.*)

```
setupPaging: function () { 
    var u = (c.vars.controlNav === "thumbnails") ? "control-thumbs" : "control-paging",
        s = 1,
        v, r;
    c.controlNavScaffold = a('<ol class="' + j + "control-nav " + j + u + '"></ol>');
    if (c.pagingCount > 1) {
        for (var t = 0; t < c.pagingCount; t++) {
            r = c.slides.eq(t);
            v = (c.vars.controlNav === "thumbnails") ? '<img src="' + r.attr("data-thumb") + '"/>' : "<a>" + s + "</a>";
            if ("thumbnails" === c.vars.controlNav && true === c.vars.thumbCaptions) {
                var w = r.attr("data-thumbcaption");
                if ("" != w && undefined != w) {
                    v += '<span class="' + j + 'caption">' + w + "</span>"
                }
            }
        }
        c.controlNavScaffold.append("<li>" + v + "</li>");
        s++
    }
    [...]
},
```

In the end, I want this for my navigation:

```
<ul>
    <li>Slide 1 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Slide 2 Title</li>
    <li>Slide 3 Fake Name</li>
    <li>Slide 4</li>
</ul>
```

I do realize for this I will need to change `<ol class="' + j + "control-nav " + j + u + '"></ol>`, but my key problem is obtaining the `data-slideName` values. How would I adapt this code to the current situation/need?

Comment: You mean this? http://api.jquery.com/data/ loop through the <ul>, get the attributes with the .data() function and modify your <ol>

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed. If you post this as an answer, I will give you due credit. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the jquery api concerning the data functionality: [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/data).
Simply loop through the `<ul>` then get the attributes with the `.data()` function and modify your `<ol>`.
Thats it :)

Best regards